# Выход из функции во время вычислений C++

Tags: c++, функции

Проблема состоит в том, что это решение я нигде не нашёл.
Мне нужно реализовать немедленное завершение функции во время, допустим, проигрывания мелодии и сделать это, допустим, с помощю потоков (мне надо, чтобы программа не завершалась, а просто прекратила выполнение функции, и пошла далее по строкам кода).

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
class Player {
public:
    void SoundPlay() {
        PlaySoundA(TEXT("lol.wav"),0,SND_SYNC);
    }
};
void cdecl StopPlayer(Player* p) {//остановка музыки
    Sleep(5000);//мелодия проигрывает 5 секунд
    delete p;//функция остается в стеке вызова и выполняется до конца,удаление объекта ничего не дает
    //SendMessageA(GetForegroundWindow(),WM_CLOSE,0,0);//работает,но завершает программу,а надо чтобы не завершало
}
int main() {
    Player* p = new Player;
    thread t(StopPlayer,p);
    t.detach();
    p->SoundPlay();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Core Audio APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista)

Comment: @VTT я имел ввиду любую функцию а не определенную

Comment: Если у этой функции отсутствует API раннего завершения работы, то прервать ее никак не получится. И PlaySoundA, и Sleep являются блокирующими функциями и не предоставляют подобного API.

Comment: @VTT а что насчет обычных функций когда они в бесконечном цикле. Коротко говоря мне нужно:достать функцию из стека и уничтожить ее чтобы вернуть управление

Comment: @VTT есть ли какой-то способ забраться в стек и убить ее там?

Comment: что значит `достать функцию из стека и уничтожить её`. Из какого стека ? Как это поможет вам прекратить её выполнение? Процессор исполняет набор инструкций. Ну то есть вы вызвали функцию - запустили набор инструкций. Удаление объекта с методом `SoundPlay` вообще никак не влияет на тот факт, что вы уже попросили процессор выполнить для вас метод `SoundPlay`, а на самом деле PlaySoundA

Comment: @vegorov то-есть это невозможно?

Comment: Как я уже написал выше, чтобы это работало, функция должна быть соответствующим образом организована. Допустим регулярно проверяет, не выставлен ли атомарный флажок прерывания работы и сразу выходит, если он выставлен. Иначе придется дожидаться окончания работы этой функции.

Comment: В линуксе я бы посоветовал поэкспериментировать с [siglongjmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/siglongjmp) или [setcontext/swapcontext](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext). Возможно вам стоит поискать аналогичный по функциональности API в windows

Comment: @avp A siglongjmp / переключения контекста разве можно выполнить для другого потока, занятого в этот момент чем-то еще?

Comment: @VTT, imho если threads native (диспетчируются ядром), то нет. Обработчик должен выполниться в рамках потока. Ну, в \*nix можно послать сигнал потоку и обработчик выполнится.

Comment: @fvBn я про пример кода который Вы привели.

Comment: по моему скромному имхо, то, что требует таких хаков, является признаком того, что вы что-то делаете не так. Можно, конечно, убивать сам поток, в котором выполняется функция на какое-то события, но лучше поискать функцию ассинхронного воспроизведения мультимедиа потока.